# How should I properly add (permanently) the PATH on bashrc on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: bash, macos, path

I am using, for the first time, the macOS Big Sur. I am used to work on ubuntu, so this is new to me. This is probably very easy but I tried everything and search everywhere and could not solve it.

I compiled a code (which works perfectly fine in ubuntu) and add the PATH to my bashrc, like this:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/joanacarvalho/Applications/FMST/bin

Then I did source ~/.bashrc and tried to run the code (named ttomoss). It should be simply type ttomoss on terminal and done. But unfortunately it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try the same on .zshrc since shell might not be bash. Test with `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Always do export ```PATH="$PATH:EXTRAS"``` - it's possible path has spaces in it already.

Comment: Are you sure the ttomoss is actual in that directory? With execute permission??

Comment: @LMC I checked and it is bash.

Comment: @Mr R it was indeed a question of PATH. I was doing it wrong because it is a bit different from ubuntu. Anyway your questions lead me to the right way to do it. I compiled the code again and now it is working. Thanks a lot.